# Shutdown function perform logoff windows while using Windows API

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I have used the following code to shutdown the system but it will perform logoff windows

```
Private Const EWX_LogOff = 0  
Private Const EWX_SHUTDOWN = 1  
Private Const EWX_REBOOT = 2  
Private Const EWX_FORCE = 4  

Public Declare Function ExitWindowsEx Lib "user32" (ByVal uFlags As Long, ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long

Public Sub ShutDownComputer()  
  Call ExitWindowsEx(EWX_FORCE, &HFFFFFFFF)   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try combining SHUTDOWN with FORCE.

Comment: And the reason for this is that FORCE is a flag, the other constants specify which shutdown operation (You could probably combine SHUTDOWN with POWEROFF, otherwise you should only specify one of the "operations")

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Private Const EWX_POWEROFF = 8 
Call ExitWindowsEx(EWX_POWEROFF, &HFFFFFFFF)
```

also this link may help you

[Why simply calling ExitWindowsEx won’t Shutdown/Restart the Computer](http://www.vbforfree.com/?p=301)

Comment: While this is correct, you really should say that 8 is EWX_POWEROFF and poweroff might not work on really old machines (Win95/NT4 era)

Comment: thanks for your response,I am using above code but still the same problem persists. I am using it in Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Eugene said, its better to use the declaration from [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.exitwindowsex):

```
Declare Function ExitWindowsEx Lib "user32" (ByVal dwOptions As Int32, ByVal dwReserved As Int32) As Int32
```

which declares as arguments two four-bytes integers (as the ExitWindowsEx function in the dll).